# How to make linux core dump file being over written each time?

Tags: linux, overwrite, coredump

I'm not using core_pattern, but I'm creating the core file under current directory, named "core". I found when there's a new crash, the core file is not overwritten, unless I manually delete the old core file, and crash will generate a new one.

Question: is there a way to make core file being overwritten, any system level trigger on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core pattern is the way you control the names of the core. (Not sure why you aren't using it)

This pattern will overwrite the core files in `pwd` The name will always be "core"

`echo core% > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`

Comment: My ubuntu says: permission denied. Even when I use "sudo".